# Pandas / Python: Groupby.apply() with function dictionary

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to implement something like this:

```
def RR(x):
    x['A'] = x['A'] +1
    return x

def Locked(x):
    x['A'] = x['A'] + 2
    return x

func_mapper = {"RR": RR,  "Locked": Locked}
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,1], 'LookupVal':['RR','Locked'],'ID':[1,2]})

df= df.groupby("ID").apply(lambda x: func_mapper[x.LookupVal.first()](x))
```

Output for column A would be 2, 6

where `x.LookupVal` is a column of strings (it will have the same value within each `groupby("ID")`) that I want to pass as the key to the dictionary lookup.

Any suggestions how to implement this??

Thanks!

Comment: Whats the problem with this solution?

Comment: first() missing 1 required positional argument: 'offset'

Comment: I also kind of guessed that using .first() was the way to do it, but I figured SO would have a better approach

Comment: Can you create a more concrete example with data and expected outputs?

Comment: Sure give me a sec.  Edits done.  Did it on my phone so apologizes if format off

Comment: what is `slice_b`?

Comment: doh, sorry.  mistake from my edit.  Fixed

Answer (score 1):

The [`first`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.first.html) is not what you think it is. It is for timeseries data and it requires an offset parameter. I think you are mistaken with [groupby first](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html)

You can use `iloc[0]` to get the first value:

```
slice_b.groupby("ID").apply(lambda x: func_mapper[x.LookupVal.iloc[0]](x))
```